# Send email with direct attachment from Xamarin app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to attach a file to my email, but I am not selecting the specific file, now I have to pre-set the file to be sent and of course, now I want the user to select any type of file from his phone or memory and It returns me the path of the file that can be photo, video or documents

```
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email2", "senha");
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.Sender = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("email2");
        mail.From = new MailAddress("email2");
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("email1"));
        mail.Subject = "Desembucha Aplicativo";
        mail.Body = " Mensagem do Aplicativo<br/> Nome:  " + nome.Text + "<br/> Email : " + email.Text + " <br/> Mensagem : " + mensagem.Text;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;

        Attachment anexado = new Attachment(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + @"/arquivo.txt", MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
        mail.Attachments.Add(anexado);

        try
        {
            client.Send(mail);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            AlertDialog alerta = builder.Create();
            alerta.SetCancelable(true);
            alerta.SetTitle("Mensagem enviada com sucesso");
            alerta.SetMessage("Aguarde em breve daremos retorno de sua mensagem, Obrigado");
            alerta.SetButton("OK", (s, ev) =>
            {
                Finish();
            });
            alerta.Show();
        }
        catch
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Error", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
        finally
        {
            mail = null;
        }
```

Comment: it sounds like your question is really "how do I allow the user to choose any file on their device?"

Comment: yes, I can not get the path from my file to attach

Comment: Attachment anexado = new Attachment(System.Environment.GetFolderPath("file path", MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);

Comment: are you sure that the path you're building is correct?  You can use File.Exists to check it.

Comment: This and the problem, which file the user will select, he can select photos, videos, documents and any area of ​​the phone, so I would have to search for this file and return the path

Comment: After I return the path of the file I will play on my command (Attachment anexado = new Attachment(System.Environment.GetFolderPath("****file path"*****, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);  )